# how to use getScript to read data from script response

Tags: javascript

I want to get the cip from the URL response. My code doesn't work. How to do this? The response from the URL is:

var returnCitySN = {"cip": "111.111.111.111", "cid": "CN", "cname": "CHINA"};

```html
$.getScript('http://pv.sohu.com/cityjson?ie=utf-8', function(data, textStatus) {
        console.log(data["cip"]);
  })
```

Comment: What does printing out the data look like?

Comment: nothing got printed out

Answer (score 0):

[`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) will fetch and run the script so all you need to do is is access the global defined in the response in your callback. Example:

```js
$.getScript('https://pv.sohu.com/cityjson?ie=utf-8', function() {
  console.log(returnCitySN["cip"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```